# How to find a optimal operation mode using matlab and matlab optimization Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have the following problem:

I have 6 different operation modes, for which I calculated the costs for each hour. (I saved this information in a matrix with 6 columns and as many rows as the number of hours. If the operation mode is not possible, i set the costs to infinity.) Everytime you want to change the operation mode there are additional costs, which depend on from which operation mode to which operation mode you switch.

Now I want to calculate the optimal timetable, but i do not have a idea how to calculate/implement it yet. I'm using Matlab and the matlab Optimization toolbox.

I'm this far.
The solution x has to be in {1,..6}^n and the objective function is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ouLO.gif)

With B being the matrix containing the costs for switching operation modes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These kind of scheduling models can be formulated as MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) models and can be solved with MIP solvers (like `intlinprog` in MatLab). For larger problems where we only can hope for good solutions instead of optimal solutions often meta-heuristics (such as generic algorithms) are used.

Let me give it a shot. I assume we cannot just use the cheapest model and use this for all 6 hours, but instead we need to run all 6 different modes, each for one period. The only thing we can vary is the ordering. I.e. we have a pure sequencing problem. (I hope this is a correct reading of your problem). We can simplify your function

[image]

by observing we can drop all terms with A(k). We do all modes so this is constant. This is a consequence of the fact that the only thing that is varying is the order in which the things are done.

I tried a quick MIP formulation, and it seems to work:

[image]

Usually there are many possible formulations, this is just one. My results with random changeover costs c(i,j) look like:

[image]

Translating this linear model into input for Matlabs `intlinprog` should not be very difficult. Missing in the model is that some modes are not allowed for some periods. We can fix this by requiring `x(i,t)=0` for those cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Bur I actually want the cheapest model. The problem I have is that I do not know how to incorporate the costs for a change of modes. So e.g this vector contains the cheapest operation modes without considering the costs for changing operation modes: (1,1,2,1,2,2)
The model has to weight up if it is worth it to change operation mode in the 3rd or 5th hour.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your description.

Comment: I have the following problem: I calculated the costs for 6 cases for every hour (there are n hours) and i saved this data in a nx6-matrix A. 
Now I want to find the optimal (cheapest) operation mode, meaning what case is chould I run for each hour. But if we want to switch cases, there are additional costs (these are saved in the matrix B). That is why my function looks like that. And the solution should look something like (1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,3,...).

Comment: Almost the same. We can delete constraint `assign1` and we need to add to the objective a term to handle the cost for `x(i,t)`. Should take you less than 5 minutes to update the above model.

Comment: I have written down the complete model [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/05/strange-scheduling-problem.html).